# What is the right way to use the R function `tally()` of `tidyverse` by different category?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I just read textbook from Benjamin, *Modern Data Science with R*. At the page 180, I find the useful function `tally()` similar to `table()` or some crosstable function. But I can't reproduce this function in my r.

The author uses this function like this way`tally(income_dtree ~ income, data = train, format = "count")`.

I simulate an example, but fail.

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50))
) %>%
  tally(~y)
```

The warning message is `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (language) of argument.`

Does anyone know how to use it?

---

Thx for @ycw. The answer is here.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mosaic)
data_frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)),
  z = c(rep("C",70),rep("D",30)),
) %>%
  tally(~ y + z, data = .)

   z
y    C  D
  A 50  0
  B 20 30
```

And the users have to add the `data = .` in the `tally()` even they use pipes.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50))) %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  tally()

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      y     n
  <chr> <int>
1     A    50
2     B    50
```

Which is the same as the follows

```
data_frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50))) %>%
  count(y)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      y     n
  <chr> <int>
1     A    50
2     B    50
```

Or this

```
data_frame(
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50))) %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      y     n
  <chr> <int>
1     A    50
2     B    50
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hi, I know simple `tally` and `group_by` & "summarise()`. I am just curious how the author do in that way. Do you know how to reproduce it?

Comment: @Jiaxiang You are probably looking at the `tally` function from the mosaic package, not the `dplyr` package. See this link for documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mosaic/versions/1.1.0/topics/tally)

Comment: Thx, it works for me. I find even using pipes, the users have to add `data = .` in the `tally()`.